# How to get the last updated date of a post from a WP RSS feed?

Tags: rss, feed

I have a third party tool which extracts feed content from our WordPress site, via our RSS feed:  http://ontariotravelblog.com/feed

The feed provides me with everything I need, except for the last updated date of the blog post;  it does include the published date, however this is simply the date the blog was first published;  edits / changes made to the blog after publication does not affect this date.

Now what's interesting is that the ATOM version of the feed (http://ontariotravelblog.com/feed/atom) does include both the published date and the updated date, for example:

```
 <entry>
  ...
    <title type="html">
        <![CDATA[8 Songs for Your Ontario Summer Road Trip Playlist]]>
    </title>
    <id>http://ontariotravelblog.com/?p=5621</id>
    <updated>2016-06-09T16:40:46Z</updated>
    <published>2016-05-10T16:25:35Z</published>
 ...
 </entry>
```

Which is great, except that the ATOM feed is missing some critical content (in particular, its missing a number of "media:" elements, such as media:thumbnail, etc.)

So after all this, my question: Is there a way to get the **updated** field which is included within the ATOM feed entry to appear on the main RSS feed?  (perhaps via some config option?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### **Atom vs RSS2**

Let's look at the `wp-includes/feed-atom.php` and `wp-includes/feed-rss2.php` files.

The `updated` element of the Atom feed entry is:

```
<updated><?php 
    echo mysql2date(
        'Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', 
        get_lastpostmodified('GMT'), 
        false 
    ); 
?></updated>
```

The `pubDate` element of the RSS2 feed item is:

```
<pubDate><?php 
    echo mysql2date(
        'D, d M Y H:i:s +0000', 
        get_post_time('Y-m-d H:i:s', true), 
        false
    ); 
?></pubDate>
```

The `lastBuildDate` element of the RSS2 channel is:

```
<lastBuildDate><?php 
    echo mysql2date(
        'D, d M Y H:i:s +0000', 
        get_lastpostmodified('GMT'), 
        false
    ); 
?></lastBuildDate>
```

### **Namespace**

The RSS2 feed already contains the *Atom* namespace:

```
xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
```

so I think we can use the `<atom:updated>` element for our custom *updated* element. You might want to check it out further, if that fulfills the standard or if there are other possible namespaces suitable for this.

For the latter case we can use the `rss2_ns` action to add the relevant namespace.

### **Inject a custom element**

We can use the `rss2_item` action to inject custom item elements, like:

```
add_action( 'rss2_item', function()
{   
    printf( 
        '<atom:updated>%s</atom:updated>',
         get_post_modified_time( 'D, d M Y H:i:s +0000', true )
    );

} );
```

Hopefully you can adjust it to your needs.

Comment: Absolutely wonderful answer - with great detail.  Unfortunately I just found out that you can't actually modify these files on sites hosted on WordPress.com - only on self hosted sites.  I had hoped there would be a config setting somewhere which would allow this, but after chatting with WP.COM support staff, apparently not.  In any case, I'm going to mark this as the correct answer as it sure sounds like it would work great, I just can't verify it myself since this is not a self hosted site.

Comment: Maybe you could join the atom+rss2 feeds with some external service or application (custom) or setup your own WordPress install  ;-) @RMD